# How to calculate output of Keras UpSampling2D Layer?

Tags: image, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I don't understand how the output of the Upsampling2d layer in Keras is calculated.
Let's take an example:

```
img_input = Input((2,2, 1))
out = UpSampling2D(size=2, interpolation="bilinear")(img_input)
model = Model(img_input, out, name='test')

input = np.array([[100, 200], [6, 8]]).reshape(1, 2, 2, 1)
model.predict(input).reshape(4, 4)
```

The result of this is:

```
array([[100. , 150. , 200. , 200. ],
       [ 53. ,  78.5, 104. , 104. ],
       [  6. ,   7. ,   8. ,   8. ],
       [  6. ,   7. ,   8. ,   8. ]], dtype=float32)
```

For me bilinear interpolation would get s.th. different. Let's take the 150 in the first row. For me this should be actually `100*(2/3) + 200*(1/3) = 133.33`. What is different in this layer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given your input array, these are the steps to apply the bilinear upsampling of `size=2`:

```py
# input array
[[100, 200],
 [  6,   8]]

# double the size and fill with existing values spreading them evenly.
#  Important! the edges of the array are not filled:
[[100,   _, 200,   _],
 [  _,   _,   _,   _],
 [  6,   _,   8,   _],
 [  _,   _,   _,   _]]

# Start filling the empty spaces sequentially by applying this rule:
#   Empty spaces surrounded by one or more filled values are filled with the
#       arithmetic average of these values.
# We would fill the entire array in two steps:
# 1. The first step would look like this:
[[100, 150, 200, 200],
 [ 53,   _, 104,   _],
 [  6,   7,   8,   8],
 [  6,   _,   8,   _]]
# 2. The second step would look like this:
[[100, 150, 200, 200],
 [ 53,78.5, 104, 104],
 [  6,   7,   8,   8],
 [  6,   7,   8,   8]]
```

If you would rather get [100, 133, 166, 200] in the first row (and the rest of the array filled accordingly), you should produce an upsampling of `size=3` and then remove the edges (res[1:5, 1:5]):

```py
img_input = Input((2,2, 1))
out = UpSampling2D(size=3, interpolation="bilinear")(img_input)
model = Model(img_input, out, name='test')

input = np.array([[100, 200], [6, 8]]).reshape(1, 2, 2, 1)
model.predict(input).reshape(6, 6)[1:5, 1:5]
>> array([[100.       , 133.33334  , 166.66667  , 200.       ],
       [ 68.666664 ,  91.111115 , 113.55555  , 136.       ],
       [ 37.333324 ,  48.888878 ,  60.444427 ,  71.999985 ],
       [  6.       ,   6.666667 ,   7.3333335,   8.       ]],
      dtype=float32)
```